# Handsontable - Calculating values that include commas

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a web page that uses [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/). In this page, I'm trying to programmatically put some data into the spreadsheet and execute some formulas. My formulas work fine until a value includes commas. For example, in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bho1rpvd/1/), I have the following code:

```
var hot =  null;

initHot();
loadFormulas();
loadData();

function initHot() {
  var container = document.getElementById('example');

  var hCols = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ];
  var hRows = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' ];
  var sdata = [
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]  
  ];

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    startRows: hRows.length,
    rowHeaders: hRows,
    startCols: hCols.length,
    colHeaders: hCols,
    data: sdata,
    formulas: true,
    height: 300
  });
}

function loadFormulas() {
  // In my app, this happens async, but I'm just plugging it in here to demo it.
  hot.setDataAtCell(2, 0, '=A1-A2');
  hot.setDataAtCell(9, 0, '=SUM(A3:A9)');
}

function loadData() {
  // In my app, this happens at runtime, but I'm just plugging it in here to demo it.
  hot.setDataAtCell(0, 0, '1000');
  hot.setDataAtCell(1, 0, '3000');

  hot.setDataAtCell(3, 0, '5000');
  hot.setDataAtCell(4, 0, '6500');
  hot.setDataAtCell(5, 0, '7000');
  hot.setDataAtCell(6, 0, '8000');
  hot.setDataAtCell(7, 0, '9000');
  hot.setDataAtCell(8, 0, '10,000');
}
```

Cell A10 should be result in the value 43500. However, it calculates incorrectly because of the comma in cell A9. When a comma is present, Handsontable views the value in the cell as zero. If you change 10,000 to 10000, it calculates properly. How do I support commas in values such that the formulas still execute correctly?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fixed the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Spreadsheet probably not calculating right because of regional settings of localmachine.  Try to change "." with "," or change  Date - Time - Number format on local machine.

Comment: My machine is US. Based on the docs, the default locale is US: https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/demo-numeric.html